# Java Arrays.binarySearch not finding first value

Tags: java, arrays, binary-search

I need to check an int[] to contain a certain value.
The array will always be sorted.

I found a method that is simple enough, but I can't get it to work properly.

When i do:

```
int[] numbers=new int[] {6,8,15,16,18,19,25,26,28,29,32};
        for(int i=0;i<40;i++) {     
            int a= (Arrays.binarySearch(numbers, i));
            if (a>0)
            {
                System.out.println("Found: "+i);
            }   
        }
```

the output is:

```
Found: 8
Found: 15
Found: 16
Found: 18
Found: 19
Found: 25
Found: 26
Found: 28
Found: 29
Found: 32
```

If i add a zero at the start of the array, then it finds the 6 (but not the zero).

Why is the first entry in my array never found?

Comment: *How* do you add 0 to the start of your array?

Comment: i meant when i do: new int[] {0,6,8,15,16,18,19,25,26,28,29,32}

Comment: Read the Javadoc. If an element isn't found the return value of `binarySearch()` is negative. Zero is not negative.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

0 = first position. As in, 'yes, I found your item; it is at the very front of the array'.

a negative number means: Not found (and if remove the sign and subtract 1 you have the location where it would have to be inserted to keep the array sorted). You're checking for 'more than 0'; you should be checking for 'more than -1'.

Comment: I see, so the returned value is the position of the element. It works now, thank you

Answer (score 0):

It should have been "if (a>-1)". If Arrays.binarySearch finds the number, then it returns the index of the search key in the array; otherwise, it returns a number that is -1 or lower. See [this link.](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/arrays-binarysearch-java-examples-set-1/)